# Rendering a React.Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Could someone point out what's wrong with this piece of code for rendering  a component using React. It keeps throwing an error saying "Element type is invalid ... check render method for App" and I can't see the problem.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';   
import App from './components/app';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

APP

```
import React from 'react';
import AppActions from '../actions/app-actions';
import Catalog from './app-catalog';

export default class App extends React.Component {
 render(){
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Catalog />
        </div>
    )   
 }
}
```

CATALOG

```
import React from 'react';
import AppStore from '../stores/app-store';
import CatalogItem from './app-catalog-item';

function getCatalog(){
 return {items: AppStore.getCatalog()}
};

class Catalog extends React.Component {
 constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = getCatalog();
 }
 render(){
    let items = this.state.items.map(item => {
        return <CatalogItem key={item.id} item={item} /> 
    });
    return (
        <div className="row">
            {items}
        </div>
    )    
 }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: let me use my divine powers to inspect `Catalog` ;)

Comment: Could you show where do you use `App`?

Comment: How is `App` being rendered? What does `Catalog` look like? There is not enough information here.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to `export default` something in `Catalog`:

```
export default class Catalog extends React.Component {
...
```

Otherwise, when you use the `import` statement nothing will import:

```
import Catalog from './app-catalog';
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `export` to `Catalog`

```
export default class Catalog extends React.Component {
}
```

because now from `catalog` there is nothing to `import`, and when you do

```
import Catalog from './app-catalog';
```

you will get `undefined` and `undefined` is not valid React component, that's why you get error